How to Customize the Title Bar in .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid App?
I am developing a .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid App and I would like to customize the title bar of the application. Specifically, I want to:

Change the appearance of the default minimize, maximize, and close
buttons to match my custom style.
Add additional controls like buttons or dropdowns to the title bar.

I have tried searching through the official documentation and various online resources, but I haven't found a clear guide on how to achieve this.
Can someone provide a detailed explanation or a code example on how to:

Modify the default title bar buttons' styles.
Integrate custom controls into the title bar.

Any help or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.

You can use the handler to customize the title bar. Here is the document you can check about the Title bar customization.

Additional explanation: Because MAUI runs both on mobile platforms (where app is full screen; there is no "window", so no title bar), and desktop platforms (where app is in a window), this is not specified via MAUI cross-platform APIs. Instead, write platform-specific code. Link in Guangyu Bai's comment is for Windows, where MAUI runs on WINUI 3, which is part of Windows App SDK.

This general answer about writing platform-specific code has some useful links (does not discuss window title): https://stackoverflow.com/a/75983322/199364

To support Windows 10, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77612115/199364.
